# how to convert image to base64 in obj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have try like this

```
+ (NSString *)base64StringFromImage:(UIImage *)image {    
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSString *base64Str = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

//    base64Str = (__bridge NSString *) CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)base64Str, NULL, CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$&’()*+,;="), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

    return base64Str;
}
```

but this return value base64Str can't be convert back to a image on a online base642image tool webstation

Comment: Probably you just need to remove `NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use following code:-

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImageView.image);
NSString * base64String = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```