# Encode / Decode PNGs to base64 strings in JXA/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cocoa, base64, applescript, javascript-automation

I am trying to write a JXA script in Apple Script Editor that converts PNG files to base64 strings, which can then be added to a JSON object.

I cannot seem to find a JXA method that works for doing the base64 encoding /decoding part.

I came across a [droplet which was written using Shell Script](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/127015) that outsources the task to *openssl* and then outputs a .b64 file:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    openssl base64 -in "$f" -out "$f.b64"
done
```

So I was thinking of Frankenstein'ing this up to a method that uses *evalAS* to [run inline AppleScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46919963), per the example:

```
(() => {
    'use strict';

    // evalAS2 :: String -> IO a
    const evalAS2 = s => {
        const a = Application.currentApplication();
        return (a.includeStandardAdditions = true, a)
            .runScript(s);
    };

    return evalAS2(
        'use scripting additions\n\
         for f in' + '\x22' + file + '\x22\n'
         do
         openssl base64 -in "$f" -out "$f.b64"
         done'
    );
})();
```

And then re-opening the .b64 file in the script, but this all seems rather long-winded and clunky.

I know that it is possible to use [Cocoa in JXA scripts](https://tylergaw.com/articles/building-osx-apps-with-js/), and I see that there are methods for [base64 encoding/decoding in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14522792/11616368)...

As well as [Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36258783/11616368):

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImageView.image);
NSString * base64String = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

The [JXA Cookbook](https://github.com/JXA-Cookbook/JXA-Cookbook) has a whole section going over [Syntax for Calling ObjC functions](https://github.com/JXA-Cookbook/JXA-Cookbook/wiki/Using-Objective-C-%28ObjC%29-with-JXA#syntax-for-calling-objc-functions), which I am trying to read over.
From what I understand, it should look something like:

```
var image_to_convert = $.NSData.alloc.UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
var image_as_base64 = $.NSString.alloc.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(image_to_convert)
```

But I just am a total noob to this, so it is still difficult for me to understand it all.

In the speculative code above, I am not sure where I would get the *image* data from?

I am currently trying:

```
ObjC.import("Cocoa");
var image = $.NSImage.alloc.initWithContentsOfFile(file)
console.log(image);
var image_to_convert = $.NSData.alloc.UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
var image_as_base64 = $.NSString.alloc.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(image_to_convert)
```

But it is resulting in the following errors:

> $.NSData.alloc.UIImagePNGRepresentation is not a function. (In
>   '$.NSData.alloc.UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)',
>   '$.NSData.alloc.UIImagePNGRepresentation' is undefined)

I am guessing it is because [*UIImagePNGRepresentation*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1624096-uiimagepngrepresentation) is of the *UIKit* framework, which is an iOS thing and not OS X?

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934940/nsimage-to-base64), which suggests this:

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"NSImageCompressionFactor"];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"1.0"];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[imageField stringValue]];
NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithData:[image TIFFRepresentation]];
NSData *tiff_data = [imageRep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:dictionary];

NSString *base64 = [tiff_data encodeBase64WithNewlines:NO];
```

But again, I have no idea how this translates to JXA.  I just am determined to get something working.

I was hoping that there was some way of just doing it in plain old JavaScript that will work in a JXA script?

I look forward to any answers and/or pointers that you might be able to provide.  Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry I never worked with JXA but a lot in Objective-C.

I think You are getting the compile errors, because You are trying to always allocate new Objects.

I think it should be the simply:

```
ObjC.import("Cocoa");
var imageData = $.NSData.alloc.initWithContentsOfFile(file);
console.log(imageData);
var image_as_base64 = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(0); // Call method of allocated object
```

0 is a constant for Base64 encodings to just get the base64 String.

```
edit:
var theString = ObjC.unwrap(image_as_base64);
```

This to make the value visible to JXA

Comment: Thank you, @ivion!  Your corrections drew no errors- but Im doing something wrong, bc I cant get it to return the base64 data (it seems to be an obj of some type)... any idea about these lines: NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"NSImageCompressionFactor"];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"1.0"];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys]; NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithData:[image TIFFRepresentation]];
NSData *tiff_data = [imageRep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:dictionary]; thx!

Comment: All these methods are used for getting the data of an image. An `NSBitmapImageRep` is an object representing a PNG, JPG, etc. It is unnecessary for your task, as You have the file and just wants to get it as Base64 String. I edited the answer and added `var theString = ObjC.unwrap(image_as_base64);`It seem without these step You don't have access to the value. This lines should work for every type of file.

Comment: Thank you so much @ivion, I was toiling over those few lines all yesterday haha- "u da man!"

Answer (score 0):

Use below code. Read the file to var file from jquery file input element using FileReader in 'readDataAsURL'. Then you will have your png as a string in base64 format.

You may need to split the base64 string with ',' to get the actual data part of the string, which you can include in a JSON and send it to the backend via an API.

```
var file = $('#fileUpload').prop('files')[0];
var base64data;
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
reader.onload = function() {
  base64data = reader.result;
  var dataUrl = base64data.split(",");
};
```

Usually the base64 string you will get be in this form.

`'data:image/png;base64,STREAM_OF_SOME_CHARACTERS...`

So the STREAM_OF_SOME_CHARACTERS...(dataUrl) is where actually the image data is in.

Furthermore you can open the image in a HTML page with

```
<img src=base64data>
```

Comment: Thanks @Anjana Senanayake, unfortunately although this code works in a regular JavaScript environment, it won't work in JXA- it doesn't recognize the FileReader object.  JXA is rather limited as is, so I think the solution lies in using Objective-C. I just cannot understand how to properly write the syntax out in JXA.  I appreciate the effort though.